# Running GDB to attach to running process get the following error ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: No such file or directory

Tags: gdb

Running GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2

When i start a process and then attach using

```
gdb -p <process#>  I get the following

Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/18/78e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/45/87364908de169dec62ffa538170118c1c3a078.debug...
0x00007fe085441fd2 in __GI___libc_read (fd=0, buf=0xe832a0, nbytes=4096)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
26  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

which is basically not attaching to the process.  But i can just run

gdb   and attach to main.  but i can't attach to a process already running

This makes it impossible to use pwntools/pwndbg
This was working and then stopped working.  I wish i knew why.

I read that I needed the source libc6 but I don't know where/how to do that.

I've tried to install libc6 but it doesn't work because its doesn't like my sources.list file.  Then i tried to follow the instrauctions for read.c and they didn't work

Answer (score 0):

> which is basically not attaching to the process

You are mistaken:

1. This isn't an error and
2. Your process *is* attached.

Without GLIBC sources you can't look inside the `__libc_read`, but looking inside wouldn't help you anyway -- your program is trying to read something from its `stdin`.

> This makes it impossible to use pwntools/pwndbg

No, it *does not*.

Comment: yes you are correct.  i am a newbie didn't realize.  I don't need gdb to see the read.c file.  I can move forward